# How to Add Children To a List C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Okay Im new to C# and have a quick question. I am learning XNA right now and I need to have a loop that will draw all my items.

```
public class DrawnObject
{
//Declare some Variables
    void draw()
    {
        //Draw Stuff
    }
}

public class child1 : Drawnobject
{
    //More Code
}

public class child2 : Drawnobject
{
    //More Code
}

public class Game1
{
    public List<DrawnObject> drawlist;
    child1 child1object;
    child2 child2object;
    DrawnObject parentobject;

    public void dosomthin()
    {
        drawlist.Add(child1);
        drawlist.Add(child2);
        drawlist.Add(parentobject);
    }
}
```

This is what I have, regretfully it doesn't work though. it is giving me Error: 'ObjectParentTest.child1' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add types to your list, instead of adding objects (name of your field is `child1object`, `child1` is a type of your field):

```
drawlist.Add(child1object); // instead of drawlist.Add(child1)
drawlist.Add(child2object); // instead of drawlist.Add(child2)
```

Also you need to assign some value to this variables before adding them to list:

```
public List<DrawnObject> drawlist = new List<DrawnObject>();
child1 child1object = new child1();
child2 child2object = new child2();
DrawnObject parentobject = new DrawnObject();
```

And one more hint - in C# we use `Pascal` names for types. Thus it's better use `Child1` and `Child2` instead. At least you will see where the type name, and where the name of variable.

Comment: and I'm guess they need a new child1 too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code i posted up here was just a mock up of some other code I was working on. I just found that it was wanting me to check if the objects were null. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the type `child1` instead of the variable `child1object`, same with `child2`.

Comment: woops............ Messed up, thats emberassing... Thanks I feel like such an idiot though.